# POE power pass through

Tags: ethernet, magnetics, poe, gigabit

Is it possible to connect the center taps of two Ethernet magnetics to each other back-to-back to pass the power from one port to another. Does it make sense? Is anything special required?
[image]

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: The two ports will connect to a self powered Ethernet switch. Therefore the switch will not need the power from the POE. The device on these two ports will connect to POE devices on both ends.

Comment: makes sense to me ... give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed with vendor that this will work as long as the signals from each port are connected properly to a separate PHY and that each PHY provides proper impedance termination. IEEE802.3 is a point to point standard. As such you would need 1 PHY per each ICM.